# Colon operation after adjoint variables

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. Let $I$ an ideal of $R$. We have 
$$0:_MI = \cap_x(0:_Mx),$$
where $x$ runs a set of generators of $I$.

Now set $S = R[T]$ with $T$ is a variable. We have $M\otimes S = M[T]$ and $IS = I[T]$ and 
$$0:_{M[T]}IS = (0:_MI)[T]$$
by the flat extension property.

**Question:** Does there exist an element $X \in IS$ such that
$$0:_{M[T]}IS = (0:_{M[T]}X)?$$

In my problem we can assume that $M$ is also Artinian (so has finite length).

Comment: "colon operation" hurts my eyes.

Comment: @johndoe: " 'colon operation' hurts my eyes".  Only your eyes?  I want to know the number for your proctologist.

Comment: I don't think this works in general.  Let $R=M=k[X,Y]/(X^2, Y^2) = k[x,y]$ (where $k$ is a field, and lower case $x$ and $y$ are the homomorphic images of $X$, $Y$ respectively).  Let $I = (x,y) = $the maximal ideal of $R$.  Then $(0:I) = (xy)$, but I don't think there is any $g\in I[T]=IS$ such that $(0:_{R[T]}g) = xyS$.

Comment: @Pham But hold on; I'm not sure my counterexample really works (which is why I wrote it as a comment instead of an answer).  Does it?  If so, I'll repost it as an answer and you can checkmark it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not true by the example of Neil Epstein as above.

Edit: Let me finish this question.

We give a generalization for the example of Neil Epstein.

Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a Gorenstein local ring of dimension $0$ and the embedded dimension $\ell(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)>1$. We show that $M = R$ and $I = \mathfrak{m}$ are not satisfying my question.

Indeed, assume that there exist an element $x \in \mathfrak{m}S$ such that
$$0:_S \mathfrak{m}S = 0:_Sx.$$
By localization at $\mathfrak{m}S$ we get a Gorenstein local ring, says $(A, \mathfrak{n})$, such that
$$0:_A \mathfrak{n} = 0:_Ax$$
for some $x$. Since the extension $R \to A$ is flat we have $\ell(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)>1$. So $x \subsetneq \mathfrak{n}$. By the duality of Gorenstein ring of dimension $0$ we have $0:_A \mathfrak{n} \subsetneq 0:_Ax$, a contradiction.